# Triggering keyboardinterrupt only at a certain time

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to build a code where the KeyboardInterrupt exception can be triggered only at certain times.
As a simple example, I built the following code:

```
import time
from time import strftime

try:

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

except time.time()%60>30 and KeyboardInterrupt:

    print("exited")
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

Is there a simple solution that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you explain what this code is supposed to do?  And why you think `time.time()%60>30` belongs in an `except`?

Comment: Essentially I'm trying to exit the code only if it's >30 sec past the minute. The reason being that the code I'm building does several things up until 30 sec past the minute and exiting it while the code runs would cause some trouble with keeping track of variables etc.

Comment: And why you think `time.time()%60>30` belongs in an `except`?

Answer (score 0):

Catch exception first and then check if your time condition met.

```
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if time.time()%60>30:
            print("exited")  # here
            break
print("exited")  # or here as you like
```